# #TheGreatIncredibleHashTag in the chat rooms

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Why doesn't at least the chat make use of the `#` like the questions use tags, so that someone can say something in chat, then do a `#` with some text with it, and then if someone clicks on that, then it takes them to a list of chat messages using that same `#` and then string in their name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No.

This isn't twitter.  Why do we need this for the thousands and thousands of messages, and why do we need to burden SE's network and DB with another several hundred gigs of additional indexing?

Comment: Well, I actually dislike them, but was just wondering what the community thought of them. :)

Comment: The text content is already indexed. Just search the transcript.

Comment: @NathanOsman you still need an additional set of indexing to handle the hashtag matching, keep that in mind,